# Character Game - C Programming

Tags: c, character

I need some help with my code. The question is:

Write a function `void printSquare(char c, int size)`
that accepts a letter of the alphabet and a number between 3 and 10 and
generates the following rectangle of letters:

If the letter passed is `a` and the size is 4:

```
abcd
bcde
cdef
defg
```

If the letter is `W` and the size is 6, the output should be

```
WXYZAB
XYZABC
YZABCD
ZABCDE
ABCDEF
BCDEFG
```

I have been trying to debug this for a long time and cannot get anywhere and need help. This is what the code looks like right now:

```
void printSquare(char c, int size);
int main() {

    printSquare('b', 4);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void printSquare(char c, int size){
    int counter = 0;
    char letters[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
        'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        if (c == letters[i]){
            int temp = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                letters[i] = letters[temp];
                temp++;
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){
                    printf("%c", letters[i]);
                    letters[i++];
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you could write `char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` more clearly.  OTOH, if you assume a code set based on ASCII (which mainly means 'not EBCDIC and mainframes') you can compute the alphabet rather than needing the initialized array.  What should your code do if the character passed is `'2'` or `'@'` or a control character or an accented character in a single-byte code set (such as ÿ in 8859-15)?  What does it do?  Wouldn't it be a good idea to fix that problem?  Which header provides the help you need?  Which functions in that header will help?

Comment: You should also edit your question with the output when you run this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming encoding where capital and small letters are sequential (e.g. ASCII), you may consider something like this:

```
void printSquare(char c, int size)
{
    char a = ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') ? 'A' : 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            // (c - a) is the offset of c from 'A' or 'a'
            // i defines an extra offset for every line, so lines start with c, c+1, ...
            // j defines an offset for a character within line
            // % 26 makes sure that overall offset does not go beyond the alphabet length
            printf("%c", a + (c - a + i + j) % 26);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain a little more of what you're doing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added a comment, hopefully it is better now, but please feel free to edit if you feel that it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
void printSquare(char c, int size){
    if(isalpha(c) && 3 <= size && size <= 10){
        const char *table = isupper(c) ?
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" :
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ;
        char *p = strchr(table, c);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            fwrite(p++, 1, size, stdout);
            puts("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess with such approach you do not need two separate tables. You can have just one `"A...ZA...Za...za...z"` (And strictly speaking, it is not necessery to repeat the complete alphabet if `size <= 10`.)